# Retrieving all groups using SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, queue, sfdx-plugin, retrieve

I'm just wondering if there are any considerations when **retrieving** groups / queues using **SFDX**.

The problem which I'm currently facing is that I'm unable to retrieve all queues using SFDX. There are always some queues missing after retrieval and I'm not sure why. It's worth mentioning that even **Org Browser** extension in Visual Studio Code is skipping some queues.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing this problem.
The problem is that even though Queues and Roles are treated as Group in DB, they are distinguished on the retrieval side.

So to retrieve all of the queues use **Queue** metadata type instead of **Group**.